# Changing /data mount in fstab

Tags: mount

I want to change the data mount point into an image inside the actual data partition.
My stock fstab has this:

```
/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/userdata      /data        ext4   noatime,nosuid,nodev,barrier=0,noauto_da_alloc,discard  wait,check,encryptable=footer,quota
```

Would it work to do like this ?

```
/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/userdata      /pre_data        ext4   
/pre_data/media/0/data.img                  /data            ext4      noatime,nosuid,nodev,barrier=0,noauto_da_alloc,discard  wait,check,encryptable=footer,quota
```

Comment: No it won't work that way? There are multiple factors which matter. May I ask what do you want to achieve by doing so?

Comment: My phone has two slots for each partition (boot_a and boot_b, system_a and system_b, vendor_a and vendor_b...etc) except for userdata. This feature is only used for updates, but I want to exploit it to dualboot my device, but for that to work each slot needs to have a distinct data. So I thought maybe I could mount an image as /data in one of the two slots ?

Comment: If you want to go that far, then divide your `userdata` in two partitions.

Comment: I don't really want to mess up with my partition table. Some utilities (like DualBoot Patcher) make diverse mounts done from folders inside the actual data partition, but I couldn't find out what they exactly modify to do it